# Creating a function that will get multiple shapes from nested array that have coordinates of each shape

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I am currently trying to make a Javascript function that will iterate through an array that represents 1 or more shapes in a nested array and each of these nested arrays could have a variable number of coordinates to create these shapes. At the bottom I have started the beginning of what this function could look like, but having trouble thinking out the logic.

Ex:

```
//This is a single 'shape' with 3 points
var coordsingle = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]];
//This one has 3 'shapes'
var coordmultiple = [[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]],[[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8]],[[-1,-1], [-2,-2],[-3,-3],[-4,-2],[-7,-3]]];
```

output: 
coordsingle  = 1 shape

1 - coordinates [1,1],[2,2],[3,3]


coordmultiple = 3 shapes

1 - coordinates [1,1],[2,2],[3,3]

2 - coordinates [4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8]

3 - coordinates [-1,-1], [-2,-2],[-3,-3],[-4,-2],[-7,-3]

```
function extractCoordinates(shapeArray){
  let shapecount = data.length; 
  if(shapecount < 2){
   
   document.write("<br>"," The Shape count is ",shapecount,"<br>");
   document.write("<br>"," The amount of Coords ",data[0][0].length,"<br>");
   document.write("<br>",data,"<br>");

  }
  else{
// this only outputs the first nested arrays set of coordinates 
  for(var coordpairs of shapecount){
    document.write("<br>"," The Shape count is ",shapecount,"<br>");
    document.write("<br>"," The amount of Coords ",data[0][0].length,"<br>");
    document.write("<br>",data,"<br>");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So it seems to me that there are a few things going on here. First, you want to be able to take a single shape in, and output some information about that shape. *OR* you might get an array of shapes in, and be able to output that same "single-shape" information for each of those shapes.

It is do-able, but the approach is a little different. First, consider defining the function to handle a single shape array:

```js
const displayShapeInfo = (arr) => {
  return `--------------------------
  The number of endpoints is ${arr.length}
  those endpoints: [${arr.join('],[')}]`;
}
```

This is simply outputting the value as a string, but we could tell that function to return DOM elements, or return *whatever*. The point is, this function takes in an array like `[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]` and outputs something like:

```
-------------------------------------
  The number of endpoints is 3
  those endpoints: [1,1],[2,2],[3,3]
```

It takes in a 2-deep array, and outputs information for that array.

In the event of an array of shape-arrays, we have a **3-deep** array. From the root, the furthest in we can go is three arrays: the main array (outermost), the shape (mid-level), and the point (innermost). So how can we apply our single-shape-handling function in that case?

In that case, we simply want to say this:

```js
const displayShapes = (arrayOfShapes) => {
  let info = []
  for(let i=0; i<arrayOfShapes.length; i++){
    info.push( displayShapeInfo(arrayOfShapes[i]) );
  }
  return info;
}
```

That one takes a three-deep array, and applies our function to each two-deep array within the top level. And yes, for those who look for completeness, this *could* be done with `arrayOfShapes.map(displayShapeInfo)`, but that might be confusing.

And the next bit will be confusing enough. See, we still don't know if we are dealing with a two-level-deep array, or a three-level-deep array. We need to `getArrayDepth` somehow, telling us *the maximum depth of this array*. That will determine which way we want to go.

So a little googling for `finding array depth in javascript` showed me this one:

```js
const getArrayDepth = (arr) => {
  // if arr is an array, recurse over it
  return Array.isArray(arr) ?
    1 + Math.max(...arr.map(getArrayDepth)) : 
    0; // otherwise, it's 0
}
```

That function starts from the outermost array and, if it is an array, runs this same function on each of its children, adding 1 for each recursive call. It will, in short, tell us the maximum depth of each nested array.

If we know that, we can then handle both cases:

```js
const displayShapeInfo = (arr) => {
  return `--------------------------
  The number of endpoints is ${arr.length}
  those endpoints: [${arr.join('],[')}]`;
}

const displayShapes = (arr) => {
  switch(getArrayDepth(arr)){
    case 2:
      // if this is a two-deep array, it is a *shape* array.
      return displayShapeInfo(arr);
    case 3:
      // if it's three-deep, it is an *array of shape arrays*.
      let info = [];
      for(let i=0; i<arrayOfShapes.length; i++){
        info.push( displayShapeInfo(arrayOfShapes[i]) );
      }
      return info;
    default:
      // *anything else*, we haven't specified how to handle
      return 'Unknown shapes array';
  }
}
```

To see this working, https://replit.com/@TobiasParent/arraysOfShapes#index.js